# How to install Deepin desktop in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: apt, 19.04

I tried this command but it doesn't work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
```

it says

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I also tried changing "disco" to "bionic" in 
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/leaeasy-ubuntu-dde-disco.list`

but when I try to install it with this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dde
```

it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dde : Depends: dde-desktop but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-wm but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried

```
sudo aptitude install dde
```

it installs but I am not able to start dde with `startdde` because the binary is not in the path.

I also don't see any Deepin entry in login menu.

and I tried all answers in [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) and [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) but no luck.

does anyone know how can I install dde?

Comment: I guess you'll just have to wait for 19.04 support. you can't trick it into working by changing the ppa to  bionic.

Comment: There's ubuntu packages for deepin, but none of them get automatically get added to the greeter. `apt search deepin` shows there's a deepin installer, but I have no idea how to use it.